# WPF Button Dynamic Command

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF form set up as follows;

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbModules" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding OnClick}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ModuleIcon}"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding ModuleName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

In the code behind, `lbModules` is given a `List<ModuleButton>` as the ItemsSource, where `ModuleButton` is defined as follows;

```
internal class ModuleButton
{
    public ImageSource ModuleIcon {get; set;}
    public string ModuleName {get; set;}
    public ICommand OnClick {get; set;}
}
```

My problem is defining the OnClick command in a dynamic fashion. I need to do this as I am using MEF and the OnClick event is technically in a different assembly. I just need to call `module.GetForm()` but it doesn't seem to be quite that simple...

I build the ModuleButton(s) as follows;

```
Lazy<IModule, IModuleMetadata> moduleCopy = module;
ModuleButton button = new ModuleButton
{
    ModuleName = moduleCopy.Metadata.ModuleName,
    ModuleIcon = 
        Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(moduleCopy.Value.ModuleButtonIcon.GetHbitmap(),
            IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()),
    OnClick = // TODO: Somehow call moduleCopy.Value.GetForm()
};
```

I've been searching far and wide, checking various results in Google, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF) is one of my latest sources.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, try my version since Patrick's answer does not implement `ICommand's CanExecuteChanged event` so you can't compile smoothly; Also, this `RelayCommand` has overloaded 'ctor that takes only one parameter- `CanExecute` always returning true - makes it easier to use.

It is taken from MSDN magazine article [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030).

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

and

```
OnClick = new RelayCommand ((o) => 
    {
        moduleCopy.Value.GetForm();
    });
```

Comment: more complete answer. I will delete mine. (+1)

Comment: Awesome, that works just like I was hoping for and I can even expand the anonymous method. Thanks!